# How can I align text under a <hr> line properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to properly align text under a

---

line.

For example, I'm trying to get the text above the line, to match up with the text below the line.
[image]

I don't know how to align the bottom text to the top text without margin left / right hacks. How can I do this properly?

Here is my snippet:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.push {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example 1</h1>
<p class="push">This is some text</p>
<p>This is text #2</p>
<hr>
<p>Not Aligned</p>
<p>Not Aligned</p>

<br><br>

<h1>Example 2</h1>
<p class="push">This is some text</p>
<p>This is text #2</p>
<hr>
<p class="push">"Aligned"</p>
<p>"Aligned"</p>
<br>
<p>These are not "aligned" properly, and don't match up perfectly.</p>
```

Comment: Before you can align properly you need to clearly define what *"properly"* means. Do you want their middles aligned? Their inner/outer limits? How do you want the space in each row distributed? Until you define all details, *"properly"* is meaningless, beacause it can mean something else for each different individual, based on education, etc...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu properly simply means without hacks

Comment: There is no such thing as hack. All code is convention. Or, if you want, the accepted answer is also a hack. But it's a "hack" that fits your bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put wrappers (in the snippet: class `.x`) around those text pairs and use the following settings. Adjust the width setting in the second rule as needed to move them closer to or away from the center.

```css
.x {
  text-align: center;
}

.x > * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <p class="push">This is some text</p>
  <p>This is text #2</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="x">
  <p>Now Aligned</p>
  <p>Now Aligned</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.push {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.parent-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example 1</h1>
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="push">This is some text</p>
    <p>This is text #2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Not Aligned</p>
    <p>Not Aligned</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the better answer in terms of coding imo as flex-box takes a lot of the work out of future-responsive issues.

Comment: @DanielVickers I also think so and it's in every case 100% aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You can `float` the `p` element and set its width to 50%, like so:

```css
p{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

h1{
  clear: both;
}

body{
  text-align: center;
}
P:last-child
```

```html
<h1>Example 1</h1>
<p class="push">This is some text</p><p>This is text #2</p>
<hr>
<p>Aligned</p>
<p>Aligned</p>

<br><br>

<h1>Example 2</h1>
<p class="push">This is some text</p><p>This is text #2</p>
<hr>
<p class="push">"Aligned"</p>
<p>"Aligned"</p>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can align them with display: flex and justify-content: space-around. For example:

```
<h1>Example 1</h1>
<div class="align">
  <p class="push">This is some text</p>
  <p>This is text #2</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="align">
  <p>Not Aligned</p>
  <p>Not Aligned</p>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.align {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```